# Position div with center as reference point?

Tags: html, css, css-position

[image]

I have a div with dynamic text content. The amount of text varies between one word and five or ten words (with large font). Right now, it's absolutely positioned some amount from the bottom and the right of its relatively positioned parent.

However, since the content is dynamic, it looks awkward when sometimes there is more text and the text goes further into the main area of the parent. This is because right now, the reference point of the div is its bottom right corner. **Is it possible to have it positioned with the center as the reference point, as depicted above?**

The parent container is just styled as normal, with `position: relative;` and `100% width and height`

CSS for the child container is also fairly standard:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 33%;
right: 33;
```

I've tried playing with width, max-width, and min-width, but the result is still not desirable

Comment: can you provide us with your current CSS styles? how are you setting the dimensions of the inner div?

Comment: @koala_dev I've made some edits above, but not sure if it will help much. Things are pretty simple right now. I've tried playing with padding, margins and widths but things got complicated/messy and I couldn't get what is desired anyway.

Comment: You want the dive to expand from the center > outwards as more content is added?

Comment: @Vector Yes, I didn't think of it that way but I guess that's the same as what I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Compare these two fiddles using the CSS below [fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/BSVhe/4/embedded/result/) & [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/BSVhe/5/embedded/result/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="anchor">
        <div id="child">
            <h1>Some text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#anchor {
    position: absolute;
    right: 33%;
    bottom: 33%;
}
#child {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: -50%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Koala, you're a real hero around here :) Although not perfect, this was satisfactory in my situation by adding `margin-bottom: -X%;` as well. I actually tried this method of having an `#anchor` div, except with `#child` I used `position: relative;` and `left: %` and `top:Y%;`, but that didn't work.... I wonder why negative margins would work but not `top` or `left`...

Comment: So I made a test using your approach and it appears it works well also, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BSVhe/7/embedded/result/), the only thing is that it seems right and left have no problem using percentage values but top and bottom don't know how to use them, you would need a fixed value in unit for those

Comment: Huh, yeah I actually think that was the problem I observed, I just didn't recognize it was specifically `top` and `bottom` that wasn't working. That's so strange how `top` and `bottom` doesn't work but `right` and `left` do.....